# Binary classification of dated text documents with seasonality

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, text-mining, weka

I have a collection of training documents with publication dates, where each document is labeled as belonging (or not) to some topic T. I want to train a model that will predict for a new document (with publication date) whether or not it belongs to T, where the publication date might be in the past or in the future. Assume that I have decomposed each training document's text into a set of features (e.g., TF-IDF of words or n-grams) suitable for analysis by an appropriate binary classification algorithm provided by a library like Weka (for instance, multinomial naive Bayes, random forests, or SVM). The concept to be learned exhibits multiple seasonality; i.e., the prior probability that an arbitrary document published on a given date belongs to T depends heavily on when the date falls in a 4-year cycle (due to elections), where it falls in an annual cycle (due to holidays), and on the day of the week.

My research indicates that classification algorithms generally assume (as part of their statistical models) that training data is randomly sampled from the same pool of data that the model will ultimately be applied to. When the distribution of classes in the training data differs substantially from the known distribution in the wild, this leads to the so-called "class imbalance" problem. There are ways of compensating for this, including over-sampling underrepresented classes, under-sampling overrepresented classes, and using cost-sensitive classification. This allows a model creator to implicitly specify the prior probability that a new document will be positively classified, but importantly (and unfortunately for my purposes), this prior probability is assumed to be equal for all new documents.

I require more flexibility in my model. Because of the concept's seasonality, when classifying a new document, the model must explicitly take the publication date into account when determining the prior probability that the document belongs to T, and when the model calculates the posterior probability of belonging to T in light of the document's features, this prior probability should be properly accounted for. I am looking for a classifier implementation that either (1) bakes sophisticated regression of prior probabilities based on dates into the classifier, or (2) can be extended with a user-specified regression function that takes a date as input and gives the prior probability as output.

I am most familiar with the Weka library, but am open to using other tools if they are appropriate to the job. What is the most straightforward way of accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 1):

Check this example for feature concatenation. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html You might be successful in encoding the seasonality as an additional feature to use along with the features extracted from your texts.

Another example is specifically dealing with temporally correlated data https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Malicious-URL-example